# Android - Removing Key value pair from Shared Preferences

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I have a list view those will loaded from shared preference. when user clicks on delete, it should remove from list and shred preferences. My problem is, the particular item is not deleted from shared preferences, for this i used below code,

```
SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(
OptionsActivity.PREFS_NAME, 0);
int deviceSize = settings.getInt("deviceSize", 0);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
String deviceName = items.get(index);
editor.remove(deviceName + String.valueOf(items.get(index)));
editor.remove("deviceName" + String.valueOf(index));
int deviceid = settings.getInt("deviceId"+String.valueOf(items.get(index)),0);
editor.remove("deviceId" + String.valueOf(deviceid));
editor.putInt("deviceSize", deviceSize - 1);
editor.commit();
```

By this code only deviceSize-1 is working, so it seem to be deleted from list but when i see the shared Preferences file, its not.
My shared Preferences file is below,

```
   <?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8' standalone='yes' ?>
   <map>
   <string name="deviceName1">APPLE</string>//delete when click on delete
   <int name="deviceId1" value="0" /> //delete when click on delete
   <int name="deviceSize" value="1" /> //decrease by one when item deleted
   </map>
```

when user clicks on delete i want to delete these 3 lines form preference file. How to delete the whole row?The list shows only name(APPLE).

Comment: Did you call  `commit()` after?

Comment: That'll be the last line of code.  Brinda.  Please show how index and items are set.  You are also abusing sharedPreferences.  This should be done in SQLite.  You will always have problems with this code since you are trying to use a non-relational data store for relational data.

Comment: @Simon yes but it not big data to store in SQLite so, i used shared preferences.

Comment: How big the data is is not the right test.  Seriously, in the future you will wish that you hadn't used this approach.

Comment: @Simon yes you are right,Thank you for suggestion. I will use that approach. But i want to know what is the problem in above code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is mistake on line :

```
editor.remove("deviceId" + String.valueOf(deviceid));
```

it should be

```
editor.remove("deviceId" + String.valueOf(index));
```

Maybe you also want to remove the deviceSize key :

```
editor.remove("deviceSize");
```

before commiting.

Your code is not very clear. Make it more readable.

Comment: I dont want to delete deviceSize, i should only decrease the value when item gets deleted.Actually its working but those deviceName and Ids are not deleted.I tried to change that deviceId to index but not worked.

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
settings.edit().remove("deviceId" + String.valueOf(deviceid)).apply();
```